# How to retrieve BIM360 issues

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to obtain a full list of my project issues using the method described in the following document:

[Issues - GET Issues](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-GET/)

[Quality issues](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v1/containers/:container_id/quality-issues)

The list I get doesn't match the one available in the BIM360 portal. Quality issues are not common project issues.

Can you provide some examples or the set of methods available to get that information?

Comment: Hi, could you share more details about what data doesn't match?

Comment: I replied to your question send to Forge Help email alias. Is it the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

We found this thread is related to the Classic Field after having a live meeting today. To get issues from Classic Field, we need to use Classic Field API ([link](https://bim360field.autodesk.com/apidoc/index.html)) instead, not the Forge BIM360 Issues API. Forge BIM360 Issues API can access issues data of the BIM360 Field Management and Document Management only currently. They are totally different systems.